# I'm looking for a specific quote that expresses this sentiment: "money isn't everything"

Tags: word-choice, phrases, idioms, quotations

I read an interesting quote years ago that went something like:"What am I if I am rich but stupid, wicked, etc". I can't remember the quote exactly nor the author.

Can you guys help me?

Comment: Have you looked at quotation sites having to do with money?  You have as good a chance of recognizing what you're looking for as we do.

Comment: Yeah, believe you me, I have tried. I thought someone here would have come across it. But I'll continue searching thanks.

Comment: A different saying with the same sentiment is _all that glitters is not gold_.

Comment: There is "you can't take it with you."

Comment: "Riches don't make a man rich, they only make him busier." (Christopher Columbus) // "Riches get their value from the mind of the possessor; they are blessings to those who know how to use them, and curses to those who do not." (Terence) // "You can have all the riches and success in the world, but if you don't have your health, you have nothing." (Steven Adler) 
taken from [BrainyQuotes](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/keywords/riches.html)

Answer (score 0):

Jesus said something similar:

See Mark 8:35-36 English Standard Version of the New Testament (the Bible):

> For whoever would save his life will lose it, but
>   whoever loses his life for my sake and the gospel's will save it.  For
>   what does it profit a man to gain the whole world and forfeit his
>   soul?

His logic:  If eternal life is available, it would be silly to pursue riches and fail to consider how eternal life might be obtained.

Comment: *"For what profit is it to a man, if he gains the world, and loses his own soul? Matthew 16:26, I believe."*

Answer (score 0):

A few other Bible verses with similar sentiments, not sure if any of these is what you are thinking of:

> If I give all I possess to the poor and give over my body to hardship that I may boast, but do not have love, I gain nothing. - [1 Corinthians 13:3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Corinthians+13&version=NIV)
>
> You say, ‘I am rich; I have acquired wealth and do not need a thing.’ But you do not realize that you are wretched, pitiful, poor, blind and naked. - [Revelation 3:17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation+3%3A17&version=NIV)
>
> “Do not lay up for yourselves treasures on earth, where moth and rust destroy and where thieves break in and steal, but lay up for yourselves treasures in heaven, where neither moth nor rust destroys and where thieves do not break in and steal. For where your treasure is, there your heart will be also. - [Matthew 6:19-21](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+6%3A19-21&version=ESV)

Keep in mind that there are lots of English translations with minor wording variations, so you might have heard one of these in a slightly different form.

[Lots more verses about wealth here](https://www.openbible.info/topics/rich_people).